# write $(this) of Jquery in pure javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, zepto

```
    var item = $('.card');

        var pageLoaded = false;
        var waypoints = item.waypoint(function(direction) {

          if($('.content').css('display') !== 'block'){
console.log('yes it did fire here');
              $(this).addClass("animated doneAnimated" + (pageLoaded ? " fadeInUp" : ""));
          }
        }, {
          offset: '90%'
        });

        pageLoaded = true;
```

Above code worked in jquery, but I switching to zepto. I don't know why $(this) in zepto is something else. How to write in pure js to make the code work?

Comment: If by "Pure JS" you mean "Without a library of JS written by someone else" - you cannot. The `$` function creates a jQuery (or Zepto) object. You can't use the jQuery (or Zepto) library without using a library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this)` returns a jQuery object, so it doesn't make sense to ask how to implement this outside of jQuery.

What you can implement is the `addClass` function, which you can easily do using DOM:

```js
this.className += "animated doneAnimated" + (pageLoaded ? " fadeInUp" : ""));
```

That way you use vanilla javascript to alter classes.

However, zepto [already supports addClass functionality](http://zeptojs.com/#addClass) and zepto [also supports `$(this)`](http://zeptojs.com/#$()) where `this` is any DOM element.

You should look into what the waypoint function passes as an argument to your function: There seems to be something else that's wrong with your code. Can you point out the exact error message that you can and come up with a minimal testcase?

Comment: I guess it should be: `$(this.element).addClass(...);` Good point!